# VB.NET generic function for checking for a value of null

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a generic function that will check each database parameter to see if it is null, and if so, return DBNull; if not, return the object.

So here is my function:

```
Public Shared Function CheckForNull(ByVal obj As Object) As Object
    If obj <> Nothing Then Return obj Else Return DBNull.Value
End Function
```

My problem is that some of the objects I am passing to the function are Nullable. So I may pass the function a Long? or Int?, but when a nullable type is passed to the function, it is converted to its value type. So if I pass a Long? that has a value of 0, the function returns DBNull because the Long? is converted to Long and a value of 0 for a Long is equivalent to Nothing. Is there anyway to make this function work for Nullable types as well?

If not, I will just fall back to using the following statements instead of one generic funciton call:

```
IIf(nullableVar.HasValue, nullableVar, DBNull.Value))
```

and

```
IIf(nonNullableVar IsNot Nothing , nonNullableVar, DBNull.Value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not why your logic is failing. When evaluating an expression like (x=y) or (x<>y), if either argument is Nothing, VB.Net returns FALSE. Your conditional is always falling through to the ELSE clause. So instead of:

```
if obj <> Nothing then
```

try this instead:

```
if obj isnot nothing then
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As a C# developer having to write VB.NET, I am still struggling with the proper handling of 'Nothing'.

Changing '<>' to 'IsNot' fixes the problem. However, I have a problem with the answer in that, my original evaluation 'obj <> Nothing' works for all cases except when comparing a nullable value type that has a value of zero against nothing. When I pass a string to the function that is not nothing, the function correctly returns the string.

Comment: Is it that the '<>' operator converts a nullable value type back to just a normal value type, and that is why when the value type has a value of 0 the comparison fails and returns DBNull?

Comment: There is probably some implicit conversion going on. M$ loves do "help" us wimpy VB programmers. I always put Option Strict On as the first line of any code file to prevent this sort of unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about 'Option Strict On' (just took on an old VB.NET project; I'm still trying to get my head around the differences between C# and VB.NET). Turned it on for the project; 3 hours and about 1000 errors later...No more implicit conversions, and hopefully no more unexpected behavior.